# My spinlock collars keep coming loose all the time

Tags: dumbbells, weights

I have a set of iron dumbbell/barbell using 1" spinlock (York I think). Ever since new the collars come loose within a few reps even though they have a rubber insert.

I was wondering can I use other collar types on spin-lock bars, or are they only compatible with non-threaded bars? I don't want to replace my entire set, but collars of various types (I am not very familiar how they all work) all seem quite cheap.
It would save time as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these clamps, they work well in most types of dumbbell and are also quicker to lock/unlock than the screw type.

It's what I use and they never slide out - I have non-threaded (smooth) dumbbell bars and load them to the very end sometimes.

[image]

There's also this quick-lock type, I've used them at the gym (remember when we all could *go* to the gym?) and it's also very efficient. I've never tried them on my dumbbells, also it's more expensive than the clamps where I live, so I didn't bother.

[image]